# ViewHolder pattern correctly implemented in custom CursorAdapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Here is my custom CursorAdapter:

```
public class TasksAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {

    private final Context context;

    public TasksAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        this.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#newView(android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, parent, false);        

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textview = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        v.setTag(holder);

        return v;
    }

    /**  
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
     */
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Tasks.TITLE);
        int completedCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Tasks.COMPLETED);

        String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
        boolean completed = Util.intToBool(cursor.getInt(completedCol));

        holder.textview.setText(title);
        holder.textview.setChecked(completed);
    }

    /**
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#runQueryOnBackgroundThread(java.lang.CharSequence)
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {

        StringBuffer buffer = null;
        String[] args = null;

        if (constraint != null) {
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("UPPER (");
            buffer.append(Tasks.TITLE);
            buffer.append(") GLOB ?");
            args = new String[] { "*" + constraint.toString().toUpperCase() + "*" };
        }

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Tasks.CONTENT_URI,
            null, (buffer == null ? null : buffer.toString()), args,
            Tasks.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }

    /**
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        final int titleCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Tasks.TITLE);
        String title = cursor.getString(titleCol);
        return title;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckedTextView textview;
    }

}
```

Does this fall into the constraints of the ViewHolder pattern? I wasn't sure because this was a CursorAdapter, where there was no `getView`. If there are any problems or suggestions, could you please point them out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`CursorAdapter` won't call the `newView` each time it needs a new row; if it already has a `View`, it will call the `bindView`, so the created view is actually reused.

That said, as pointed out by **Joseph** in the comments, you can still use ViewHolder in order to avoid calling `findViewById` repeatedly.

If you are still concerned about efficiency then take a look at the [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java&q=simplecursoradapter.java%20android&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) implementation, which uses a `WeakHashMap` (a map of `WeakReferences`):

```
WeakHashMap<View, View[]> mHolders = new WeakHashMap<View, View[]>();
```

Comment: So I can make expensive calls like View.findViewById(int) and my application won't lag?

Comment: `findViewById(int)` is not as expensive as you think. It will only return a reference (if any exists). ViewHolder technique exists to solve other kind of problems: don't create more Views than what you really need (thus, it avoids excessive view inflations, which IS expensive).

Comment: @Cristian, thank you. I used `newView` and `bindView` to make a class extends `SimpleCursorAdapter`. See the code below.

Comment: @Cristian I think your comment is wrong. View Holder actually exists to avoid multiple findViewById calls, as said here: http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70?t=10m50s Moreover, to solve the problem you talk about (don't create more Views than what you really need) another technique is used, based on the convertView.

Comment: @Joseph82 well... calling findViewById multiple times is the least of your concerns. You actually use ViewHolder in order to avoid **inflating** the view a lot of times, which is too expensive. The video actually is correct, but your interpretation of it is not. If you need me to elaborate more on this let me know.

Comment: @Cristian You are wrong again! From the Commonsware book [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lmm5tieqyrqiqk/ListView_optimization.JPG) you can find an implementation of getView() without ViewHolder, but that uses the convertView. As you can see, when convertView is not null, no inflating is required: the view is recycled. So, in order to avoid inflating you have to use the convertView. Instead ViewHolder  is actually used for avoiding many findViewById calls, as said in the same commonsware book [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5txi0o3xa422emt/ViewHolderPattern.png)

Comment: @Cristian also, have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) where it says **"A way around repeated use of findViewById() is to use the "view holder" design pattern."**

Comment: I see it now. Avoiding the inflation is provided by the convertView instance, while ViewHolder is only used as a way to avoid `findViewById` calls. Thanks for making this clear to me!

Answer (score 8):

If you are overriding `newView()` and `bindView()`, you don't need to do anything extra in `getView()`. `CursorAdapter` has an implementation of `getView()` that delegates to `newView()` and `bindView()` to enforce the row recycling.

`findViewById()` maybe called frequently during the scrolling of `ListView`, which can slow down performance. Even when the `Adapter` returns an inflated view for recycling, you still need to look up the elements and update them. To avoid this, `ViewHolder` pattern is useful.

Here's an example of `ViewHolder` pattern implemented for a weather app:

```
public class ForecastAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public ForecastAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_forecast, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        long date = cursor.getLong(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_DATE);
        viewHolder.dateView.setText("Today");

        String weatherForecast =
                cursor.getString(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_DESC);
        viewHolder.descriptionView.setText(weatherForecast);

        double high = cursor.getFloat(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP);
        viewHolder.highTempView.setText("30");

        double low = cursor.getFloat(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP);
        viewHolder.lowTempView.setText("24");

        int weatherConditionId =
                cursor.getInt(ForecastFragment.COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID);
        viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_snow);
    }

    /** Cache of the children views for a list item. */
    public static class ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView iconView;
        public final TextView dateView;
        public final TextView descriptionView;
        public final TextView highTempView;
        public final TextView lowTempView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            iconView =
                    (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            dateView =
                    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_date_textview);
            descriptionView =
                    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_forecast_textview);
            highTempView =
                    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_high_textview);
            lowTempView =
                    (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_low_textview);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My implementation of a class extends SimpleCursorAdapter with `newView` and `bindView` but without the `ViewHolder` pattern

```
    private class CountriesAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public CountriesAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from,
                    int[] to, LayoutInflater inflater) {
                super(getActivity(), layout, cursor, from, to, CURSOR_ADAPTER_FLAGS);
                mInflater = inflater;
            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.countries_list_row, parent, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View rowView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.countriesList_tv_countryName);
                TextView tvOrgs = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.countriesList_tv_orgNames);
                ImageView ivContinent =
                        (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.countriesList_iv_continentName);

                // TODO: set texts of TextViews and an icon here
                }

            }
    }
```