# Listview items Animation Stop While Scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to show `ProgressBar` with a simple animation for each `ListView` item, but
when I am scrolling, the `ProgressBar` animation stops. After scrolling ends the animation starts again.
See image below.

[image: Link]
<sub>(source: [axgig.com](https://www.axgig.com/images/39297660841936639268.gif))</sub>

Comment: For the close votes because unclear what the OP is asking, I think it's pretty obvious on the contrary. He want to know how to keep the progress bar animation when scrolling occurs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used This Syntax in my Adapter And problem solved !

```
public class AdapterDownload extends ArrayAdapter<StructDownload> {

public AdapterDownload(ArrayList<StructDownload> array) {
    super(G.context, R.layout.item_layout, array);
}


private static class ViewHolder {

    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {

    }


    public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<StructDownload> adapter, final StructDownload item, final int position)
    {

    }
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

}
```

}

Thank You.

Answer (score 13):

you must use animation in getView() and set animation for convertView
example :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    StructureArticles item = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_articles, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.fill(this, item, position);
    Animation animationListView = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_fade_in);
    convertView.startAnimation(animationListView);

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is stopping because getview is called again and again when list items are visible thus resetting the view to avoid any frame skips/lag on the devices..

what you need to do is to create a view holder with boolean and set it as a tag to the view.. each time is it animating boolean should be true and false when it stops.. so when getview is called your progressbar animation is still starting or stopping depending on the boolean..