# viewpager gallery with circle indicator and lazy loading images

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-lazyloading

I want to load some images from web into a viewpager (Lazyloading) with viewpager having circle indicator.

I mean before loading images, a simple image is displayed and after image being loaded from web, they must be replaced. 
I have a library for viewpager with circle indicator [here](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow), but can't use it for lazyloading.
And I have a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) for lazy loading images but it's not viewpager with circle indicator.

Please help.

Comment: before displaying you need to show a progress bar ?

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933529/design-of-list-view-lazy-loading-images-component/13934045#13934045 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080117/universal-image-loader-wrong-bitmaps-are-attached-to-imageview/14080147#14080147